# 2 indexes with same alias but only one is marked as write index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 indexes in Elastic search which are having the same alias name but only for one of them, **is_write_index** is true. Now, when I try to write to the indexes by alias name, I am getting following error:

```
Alias [alias_name] has more than one indices associated with it [[indexname1, indexname2]], can't execute a single index op
```

This is something I am doing which is failing:

```
  let doc = {
      script: {
        source: ...,
        lang: "painless",
        params: {
          ...document
        }
      },
      upsert: {
        ...document
      }
    };
   await client.update({
    index: alias_name,
    id: docId,
    body: doc
  });
```

What can be the issue here? My thinking was if only one of them is marked as write index, it would just write to that and writes should not fail (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#aliases-write-index). Am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Can you show what operation are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using Update API of elasticsearch from Node JS code: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/update_examples.html

Comment: It's easier if you show what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an update is a [combo operation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#update-api-desc) where the document is first retrieved using GET, then updated using the script and finally reindexed using the index operation.

What doesn't work in your case is the first operation as GET cannot be done over an alias that spans multiple indexes, even if only one of them as the `is_write_index` flag set to true, there's no guarantee that the document to be updated is actually in that index.